# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification doesnt work from iOS > 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6.1

Init section:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Some method:

```
- (void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
// TO DO 
}
```

Dealloc section:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

So keyboardWillShow is not called after presenting view in iOS 6.1...
In iOS 6.0 this code works perfectly.

Comment: Are you only having this issue on the iPad or does the issue exist on the iPhone and iPod touch too?

Comment: My code is exactly like yours, except for the dealloc, I don't use it. Could you post some more code?

Comment: It is working perfectly for me, I'm using it all the time. Works on iPad as well as on iPhone and on iOS 6.1.x as well as on iOS 6.0... (although I don't remove the observer at any point and most of the time, I leave the target method without parameters or use (id)object instead)

Comment: Make sure your dealloc section (I don't know where is) doesn't get called before you show the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

In which "init section" are the observers being added?  If your view controller is from a storyboard, for example, then it should be in `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder`.

My recommendation, however, is to set up the observers in `viewWillAppear` and remove them in `viewWillDisappear`.  That way the setup and tear down are "balanced" and only active when the view controller's content is visible.